# Faster Air On Tuba

Tags: breathing, tuba

My tuba teacher tells me to play with faster Air in the high range, but I'm not sure what he means. Every time I use faster air, I inevitably crescendo to a point that's no longer passable in the music. Does anyone have any advice or tips on how to have a better airflow on tuba?

Comment: Is this really a dup? The op seems to know what faster air is, the problem is more that the volume changes when he/she does so, whereas the dup explains what faster air means.